# Facebook android sdk FacebookDialog stop working to share link

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I tried use Facebook SDK, FacebookDialog in Android app to share. It works sometimes me and others.

But me I can't share. When I push the "Post" on dialog screen, it falls back with this Toast message: "Something went wrong. Please try again."

```
private void sharePlaceOnFb(PlaceForShare data){
        if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getActivity(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(getActivity())
                    .setName(data.getName())
                    .setLink(data.getUrl())
                    .setDescription(data.getType()+" @ "+data.getCity())
                    .setPicture(data.getImg())
                    .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        }
    }
```

This is in a Fragment.

One interesting things:
The url what I want to share it is an IDN domain name (xn--***). And if I change it to normal other link everything works again. So what's the problem? The Facebook Debugger not show any error with my link. Facebook have problems with IDN domains? Or what I want to do? I say again, it's worked sometimes (with IDN domain).

### UPDATE

**With this URL format NOT work:**

www.xn--holegynk-c6a.***/xyz/blablabla (this is an accent domain: www.holegyünk)

**With this URL format WORK:**

www.holegyunk.***/xyz/blablabla (this is a normal domain format)

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade I don't know. adb can't install FB apk to test it on AVD.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse ? If yes, please report to the logcat

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade Yes. But if Facebook SDK not installed on AVD, Facebook fetures not work. I can test only on real device.

I think the IDN domain is wrong. If I change my link url "www.xn--holegynk-c6a.****" to another, like "www.holegyunk.***" then everything OK, and posted to my wall.